# How to concenate / merge data row into an object

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to merge data row into an object.

For example :

```
Declare @Email as varchar(max);

Select @Email=email from M_Employee
```

I want to merge all email into @Email with ';' as separator.

Comment: This is a very common question. Have a [Google](http://www.google.com/) of `STUFF`, `FOR XML PATH` and delimited string. if you get stuck with the syntax, edit your post with what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select 
@Email=LEFT(l.list,LEN(l.list)-1)
FROM
(
SELECT  Email + '; ' AS [text()]
FROM M_Employee
FOR XML PATH('')
)l(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You you can use [`STUFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql), with [`FOR XML`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server):

```
SELECT @Email = STUFF((SELECT distinct ';' +
                        email 
                       FROM M_Employee AS t
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');
```

This will give you all the emails comma separated with `;`.

- [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/789c9/3)

Comment: @Downvoter, care to explain??!!!!!!!! whats wrong with the answer???? or show us your fancy answer instead!!!!!!!!!1

Comment: The op wants the emails comma separated with `;` and this is what my answer does, then whats wrong????????!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Somebody around here to Down vote without any reason. Leave it. Cheers...!+1